# Правописание глаголов

Tags: глаголы, орфография

Глаголы охладЕвать, недоумЕвать, почему Е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К глаголам, оканчивающимся на ударяемые "-вать", "-ваю" (охладевать - охладеваю, недоумевать-недоумеваю, околевать - околеваю, одолевать - одолеваю и т.п.) подбираются проверочные слова: охладевать (охладеть), недоумевать (недоумение), околевать (околеть), одолевать (одолеть). Исключение составляют слова "застревать, затмевать, продлевать, разевать, растлевать, обуревать.

Comment: А как же правило? Почему его нелья применить в данных случаях?
 Для проверки определи форму 1-го лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени.

Если в форме 1-го лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени есть

ую, юю, то пиши суффиксы ова, ева: советовать — советую, командовать — командую.
ываю, иваю, то пиши суффиксы ыва, ива: опаздывать — опаздываю, рассматривать — рассматриваю

Comment: Все дело в ударении?Я поняла спасибо.

Comment: Вы процитировали первую часть правила. После  того, что Вы пересказали, в правилах говорится: "Исключение составляют глаголы с ударяемым "вать-ваю" и далее так, как я уже писал в ответе